# Are jQuery plugins supposed to be defined in document ready?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery. After unsuccessfully trying to use a few jQuery plugins I downloaded, I examined $.fn, and saw that anything being added to it was missing by the time the document ready handler is called. It also fails in event handlers such as onclick.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function () { alert("success"); };

    //works fine - alerts with "success"
    $(document).myPlugin();

    $(function () {
        //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'myPlugin'
        $(document).myPlugin();
    });
</script>
```

If I move the definition of the plugin inside the document ready handler, everything works fine after that (including event handlers). Is that how it's supposed to be done? Everything I've found online clearly suggests otherwise. I'm using Chrome and its built in developer tools. Thanks.

Comment: Just realized that jQuery is getting added by a second <script> tag towards the end of the html file. It's being reinitialized, and therefore the plugin is lost.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/tzjvS/. Can you reproduce that in a jsfiddle? The DOM shouldn't need to be ready for you to extend the jQuery object, they are unrelated...ah hence your update, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.   The document ready callback is there so that you'll know when all your DOM elements and jQuery are ready for use.  The actual code doesn't have to be inside the callback, but you should only initialize your plugin once all the elements are ready for use.

For example, an `on('click')` handler **must** be in the document ready callback but the function it executes doesn't have to be -

```
$("#button").on('click',function(){
  btnClickHandler(); // this can be defined outside the ready callback.
});
```

So you see, the code itself is not required to be encapsulated with the ready callback, but the code that executes the plugin *should* be there, because only then do you know that your document is ready to be manipulated...

It's always a good idea to place your code within a document ready callback.  You can also have multiple document ready callbacks in different files - each will be called as soon as your DOM is ready.  In the event of multiple ready callbacks, the order in which you write them to your page will dictate what gets executed first.  Always reference jQuery first so that your ready callback will be executed.

- [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Sorry, dude. I figured it out. BTW, Plugins are NOT supposed to be defined inside the ready handler.

Comment: @bre - yes, sorry, my answer was slightly vague with regard to that.  You are right.  The plugin code doesn't have to be there, but the code that initializes/executes the plugin functionality needs to be in the ready callback...